# How to get section titles to be top-aligned with the actual text contents?

Tags: sectioning, nicematrix, unnumbered-sections

I am trying to write a course syllabus which should look like this

[image]

The example above is done using `NiceTabularX` environment. My questions are as follows

1. The document will actually extend across multiple pages, which means the design above should be done using `\section*` command for each heading (Course title, Objectives, and Catalogue description) and column on right should be the actual text available for typesetting after sections
2. Section title should be of (fixed width `2in` in this example) and be top-aligned with the contents including enumerations
3. Spacing before and after section titles should be adjustable (at least in the main redefinition of `\section*` command)

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in,showframe=true}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

{\bfseries \huge \hspace*{\fill} Control Theory I\space Course Syllabus \hspace*{\fill}}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\Large}p[l]{2in} X[1, t, l]@{}}[cell-space-limits=1.1961pt]
    
    Course Title & Control Theory I
    \\
    
    Objectives & \vspace{-2.1mm} \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
        
                \item Understand the fundamentals of control systems
                
                \item Understand Laplace transform theorems
                
                \item Understand block diagram reduction (including Mason's rule)
                
                \item Understand the specifications of first-order and second order systems
                
                \item Understand state-space modeling of systems dynamics
        
    \end{enumerate}
    \\
    
    Catalogue description & \blindtext
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

- Set the header using `center` (and appropriate formatting)
- Set the rest of the document as a narrower, single column pushed to the right.
- Headings (or `\newsection`s) set themselves in the margin (with appropriate formatting).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry,changepage}
\geometry{margin=0.5in,showframe=true}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}% Space between sections
  \makebox[0pt][r]{% Set the section in the margin
    \makebox[\lmarginwidth][l]{\bfseries \large \strut #1}%
  }\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\lmarginwidth}
\newenvironment{coursedetails}[1][.3\linewidth]{%
  % coursedetails sets a right-hand column to hold the main body, with sections in the left margin
  \setlength{\lmarginwidth}{#1}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{\lmarginwidth}{0pt}
}{%
  \end{adjustwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries \huge
  Control Theory I -- Course Syllabus
\end{center}

\begin{coursedetails}

  \newsection{Course title}
  Control Theory I
  
  \newsection{Objectives}
  The following objectives will be targeted:
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
    \item Understand the fundamentals of control systems
    \item Understand Laplace transform theorems
    \item Understand block diagram reduction (including Mason's rule)
    \item Understand the specifications of first-order and second order systems
    \item Understand state-space modeling of systems dynamics
  \end{enumerate}
  
  \newsection{Catalogue description}
  \lipsum[1-10]
  
\end{coursedetails}

\end{document}
```